# How best to Access Php Static Variables from another Php file

Tags: php

I have a static variable like so to keep track of some operations in memory without using a real database

```
<?php

class Database
{
    public static $database = array();
}
```

When I try to access the database from another php file like so

```
<?php
include 'database.php';

function createPaymentRef($username, $password, $amount)
{
    $finalResult = array();
    $ref = generateTimedTransactionRef($username, $password, $amount);
    global $requestData;
    global $ip;
    Database::$database->unset($username); //Expected type 'object'. Found 'array'.intelephense(1006) error

    $requestData->ip = $ip;
    $requestData->reference = $ref;

    $finalResult['result'] = $ref;
    return $finalResult;
}
?>
```

I am get an error saying

```
Expected type 'object'. Found 'array'.intelephense(1006)
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->` is used to access properties or methods of an object. `Database::$database` is an array, not an object. The syntax to unset an array element is

```
unset($array[$index])
```

so it should be

```
unset(Database:$database[$username]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the static variable exists and if the array element in it exists, then unset using `unset(Database::$database[$username])`:

```
$db = Database::$database;
if($username && $db && isset($db[$username])){
  unset(Database::$database[$username]);
}
```

Comment: That makes a copy of the array, it doesn't unset the original array element.